# Writing texts in two parallel columns

Tags: two-column

I need to quote an excerpt of a book along with its translation, but I don't know how to write the original text in the left of my document and the translated one in the right of the same page.

The document class is `book`, and my document is written full page, not divided in columns.

Can you help me?

Comment: Try the `paracol` package, for example

Comment: Do you need the text one in each page or in the same page?

Comment: `multicol` is another option

Comment: @ChristianHupfer The paracol package seems good. Is there a way to change the column width? (There is too much empty space between columns) And is it possible to change the size of the text only in the paracol environment?

Comment: @Alenanno In the same page

Comment: @M-elman: If I remember correctly, the column widths can be changed

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Can you tell me how? And if is it possible to change the size of the text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use, possibly amongst other choices, [`paracol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/paracol) or [`parcolumns`](http://ctan.org/pkg/parcolumns). Each have their own option to specify/choose from.

---

#### `paracol`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage{paracol,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\sloppy% Just for this example
\lipsum[1]

\columnratio{0.4}
%\setlength{\columnseprule}{.4pt}
\begin{paracol}{2}
  \lipsum[2]
  \switchcolumn
  \lipsum[3]
\end{paracol}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

---

#### `parcolumns`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage{parcolumns,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\sloppy% Just for this example
\lipsum[1]

\begin{parcolumns}[colwidths={1=.4\linewidth},rulebetween]{2}
  \colchunk{\lipsum[2]}
  \colchunk{\lipsum[3]}
\end{parcolumns}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Paracol suits me, I tried it and it seems the solution for what I need to do. Now however I need to do some changes to columns and the text in them: in the matter in question I want to decrease the space between the columns and, if it is possible, to decrease also the font size, in order to make the text occupy less space in the page.

Comment: @M-elman: Are you just translating *terms*, or are you translating *paragraphs*? Will you only use *one* page for this, or *more than one*?

Comment: I'm translating an excerpt of an article - so, paragraphs - and I want to use only a part of a page for this. With default settings the section occupies a full page and it' unsightly.

Comment: @M-elman: So you have `\section*` *inside* the environment you want to translate? Please provide as much detail as possible. Alternatively, provide an image...

Comment: In the current chapter of my document I have the section "MySection". I wrote something in it and then I need to quote a piece of a scientific article, which I prefer to quote in the original language and translated, preferably in two columns, under the text above, but without changing the settings of all the document. Since it's an example, I would like to write it without occupying a full page, hence the need to reduce the font size and the space between columns. Did I manage to clarify everything?

Comment: @M-elman: Look at [this paste](http://pastebin.com/FjcjNpzR). You can adjust the font size by adding some font switch (like `\small`, as in the linked example). I've manually set the section titles, if you have any you want to translate, and made the column switching sync up. You can change the column widths using `\columnratio{<ratio>}` or `\setcolumnwidth`.

Comment: `\small` worked perfectly. Now I know that is the opposite of what I asked before, but one last thing: how can I increase the space between the two columns? (It appeared to be too much due to the `quote` environment and now is too little)

Comment: @M-elman: Add `\setlength{\columnsep}{5em}` before the `paracol` environment. Change `5em` to suit your needs.